# How to use np.where on list of Python objects to return inner objects matching condition?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, where-clause

Trying to further master Python, I am struggling to implement what seems like a basic search task over a list in vectorized numpy.

I have a list of dictionaries, and I want to select those dictionaries that have a certain key:value pair, which will be my truth condition. My intuition is to use `np.where` on the list, since this function gives back members of a list that match a specific condition. But `np.where` seemingly does not allow specifying any inner attributes/sublists of a member of the list.

For example, the following code gives me a `TypeError` for the list indices,

```
dictionaries = [{'name':'Koko', 'value':1},
                {'name':'Sam', 'value':2},
                {'name':'Mike', 'value':3},
                {'name':'Bob', 'value':4},
                {'name':'Alex', 'value':5}]

names_to_check = ['Koko', 'Bob']

search_results = np.where(dictionaries['name'] in names_to_check)
```

I know I could always make a `for loop` to handle this problem manually.

Am I right in using `np.where` here, or is there some better way to vectorize this task?

Comment: numpy doesn't play well with dictionaries, you need to have arrays for it and if you store dictionaries in an array you lose all the advantages of numpy. Instead, you can convert this to a pandas DataFrame (`df = pd.DataFrame(dictionaries)` and filter with `df[df['name'].isin(names_to_check)]`.

Comment: Where returns the indices where the argument array is true. So it's only as good as that argument. But with a list of dictionaries there isn't a fast numeric way of testing values.

Comment: Converting the whole problem to Pandas would certainly make things easier, but Pandas has a lot of overhead, however. Is there maybe another way to vectorize this situation while preserving the dicts (which unfortunately are part of the data I have)?

Comment: You might try working with `list(dictionaries.items())`,

Comment: I don't think there is a way to vectorize this without turning the dictionaries to numpy arrays / pandas series.

Comment: Vectorization is a feature of numpy which is best exploited by having numpy arrays of numeric primitives. Otherwise all the advantage is lost. If you aren't willig to convert, there is no point in mixing up numpy with your list of objects

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `numpy` I would rather go with `filter`:

```py
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x["name"] in names_to_check, dictionaries))
[{'name': 'Koko', 'value': 1}, {'name': 'Bob', 'value': 4}]
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
search_results = [x['name'] in names_to_check for x in dictionaries]
print(search_results)

[True, False, False, True, False]
```